# slick carousel not displaying / working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, slick.js

I'm using https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick as a carousel for my website. I have followed the tutorial to a T, everything is (to my knowledge) how its meant to be. here's the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
  $(".slider-nav").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll, 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider',
    dots: true,
    focusOnSelect, true
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Semantic import-->
  <script src="assets/semantic/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/semantic/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- Slick -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <!--Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="js/root.js"></script>
  <script src="js/gamesdev.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="pusher">
    <div id="page">
      <div class="ui container">
        <div class="slider">
          <div><h3>1</h3></div>
          <div><h3>2</h3></div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've cut out all the unnecessary code but here is the result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EiSo.png

I have no damn clue what's going wrong, I've combed through it for like an hour, maybe two.

Comment: `ERROR: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 66,
  "colno": 22
}`

Change `slidesToScroll, 1` to `slidesToScroll: 1`

Comment: no avail, even if that was the case the second carousel would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not working because of a syntax error. You have a comma instead of a colon

Change `slidesToScroll, 1,` to `slidesToScroll: 1,`

And change `focusOnSelect, true` to `focusOnSelect: true`

Comment: still hasn't fixed it.

Comment: @LamarTonyDaughma there's another comma instead of a colon after focusOnSelect. That should fix it

Comment: No problem, we've all been there haha

Comment: because I'm dumb, could you tell me why it breaks both carousels? i am still pretty new to JS

Comment: I'm not really familiar with error handling in JS, I know that when an exception is thrown it will stop other code from running just like in other languages with exceptions. Might be interesting to look into it though, that's the best way to learn about it ;)